# No validator could be found for type: Enum

Tags: java, spring, validation, enums

I get exception for validation of Enumaration:

> WARN
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:186
>   - Handler execution resulted in exception: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: enum.YesNo

All classes are below :

```
public enum YesNo {
    YES("Yes"), NO("No");
    private String value;

    YesNo(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class Bean {
    @NotNull
    @EnumValidator(enumClazz = YesNo.class)
    private YesNo yesno;
}

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = EnumValueValidator.class)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EnumValidator {
    Class<? extends Enum<?>>enumClazz();

    String message() default "Value is not valid";

    Class<?>[]groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[]payload() default {};
}

public class EnumValueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EnumValidator, String> {
    List<String> valueList = null;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final String value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (!valueList.contains(value.toUpperCase())) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(final EnumValidator constraintAnnotation) {
        valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass = constraintAnnotation.enumClazz();

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Enum[] enumValArr = enumClass.getEnumConstants();

        for (@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Enum enumVal : enumValArr) {
            valueList.add(enumVal.toString().toUpperCase());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are putting the annotation on YesNo field, but the validator implementation is for String fields. Hence the error that there is no Validator for YesNo type.

Comment: @Ozturk, wondering if you found any solution for the above? I'm facing the same. would appreciate if you share the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA - No validator could be found for type: enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937076/jpa-no-validator-could-be-found-for-type-enum)